# Off Topic Flag -> Server Fault?

Tags: support, flags

Today I had Several Posts like this both:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165785/how-to-set-apache-and-makes-php-could-run-exec-in-mac-os?noredirect=1#comment44737195_28165785

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184035/mail-log-for-php-mails

About Server Config. 
I would say they are off Topic since SO is not about Server  Config, but also they are not really Professional.

The reason for that Off-Topic Bullet

> Questions on **professional** server- or networking-related infrastructure
>   administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly
>   involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help
>   on Server Fault.

For what should I flag such Off Topic Server Question with non-Professional Background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first question was nearly indecipherable, so it shouldn't be migrated anywhere. I went with "unclear what you're asking". The second was removed by the asker.

In any case, Server Fault has very high standards as to what's acceptable over there. Unless absolutely certain, we tend not to migrate things there when flagged.

Server Fault was removed as a migration target from the list [due to how badly that was working](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3853/should-server-fault-be-removed-from-stack-overflows-migration-list). In its place, the standard off-topic reason of

> Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

is usually used for non-programming networking questions on Stack Overflow.